# How to get .text segment statistics in IDA Pro?

Tags: windows, assembly, reverse-engineering, ida, memory-segmentation

Is there any way to show how many bytes in .text segment IDA Pro treats as instructions and how many as data? Are other statistics also available (e.g. function sizes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function sizes are shown in the functions list. But there is no built-in functionality for the code/data bytes counts. You will need to use scripting (IDC or Python), or write a plugin using the IDA SDK to calculate it. I'd recommend posting this question on the [Hex-Rays user support forum](https://www.hex-rays.com/forum/).